# How to Avoid Re-Rendering All Components After a Shift

Tags: reactjs

Imagine that this vim buffer is a React component called `BufferComponent` and each row of the buffer is a `RowComponent`.
[image]

Notice that the caret is positioned at the end of the buffer. When I press the `j` key, every row should move up revealing row 37 and hiding row 12. The following is a simplified code that implements this behaviour; you can also find the full version [on Github](https://github.com/black-screen/black-screen/blob/master/src/views/BufferComponent.ts).

```
class BufferComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return React.createElement('pre', {},
            this.props.buffer.map((row, index) => React.createElement(RowComponent, {row: row, key: index}))
        );
    }
}

class RowComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return React.createElement('div', {},
            this.props.row.map((char, index) => React.createElement(CharComponent, {char: char, key: index})) 
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i press `j`, every row is re-rendered with its new content. Now, if I manually manipulated the DOM, I'd just remove the first row's `div` and add another one at the end, which would result in the minimal amount of DOM manipulations.

How would I make ReactJS do this instead of re-rendering every single row? I suspect I have to at least use a key not connected to a row index, but that alone isn't enough.

Comment: I believe you want the key to be a unique id and not the map's index

Comment: Do you have an advice how to generate a proper key?

Comment: If you're getting data from a server then use the unique id from the db or you could use something like `simple-unique-id` (npm). However, I believe that React aims to avoid inserting/removing elements (the manual way you said) and instead reuses elems by changing the contents. It does a delta of the virtual dom against the real dom. Are you certain the elements are re-rendered and it's not just the content changing?

Comment: Or if you have the 'real' row-numbers from your example (12, 37 etc), you could use those.